# AngularJS testing directives with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm trying to use [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) to test AngularJS directives. But I'm running into issues with templateUrls. Using technique described [here](http://tylerhenkel.com/how-to-test-directives-that-use-templateurl/), it gets even stranger. It seems to work as advertised and loads my template into the $templateCache, but that cache isn't being used by the directive. Here's some code:

This will work just fine

```
.directive('messageComposer', function($templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: $templateCache.get('partials/message_composer.html'),
    replace: true,
    link: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };
});
```

but as soon as I use a templateUrl, it fails to bind in the tests:

```
.directive('messageComposer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/message_composer.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function() {
      console.log('hello world');
    }
  };
});
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Here's my unit test setup:

```
var $scope;
var $compile;

beforeEach(function() {
    module('partials/message_composer.html');
    module('messageComposer');

    inject(function(_$compile_, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile = _$compile_;
    });  
});


it("works", function() {
    $scope.message = {};
    elem = angular.element("<message-composer message='message'></message-composer>")
    $compile(elem)($scope);

    console.log(elem);

    expect(true).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the url (http://tylerhenkel.com/how-to-test-directives-that-use-templateurl/), I believe you have run the following command:

```
npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev
```

Now when you are using the above preprocessor, then this preprocessor will convert HTML files into JS strings and will generate Angular modules. These modules, when loaded, puts these HTML files into the $templateCache and therefore Angular won't try to fetch them from the server.

Hope, the following files will clarify you better:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing

Comment: That seems to work for the most part, but strangely my directives still don't like the `templateUrl`. If I use `template: $templateCache.get('...'),` it works fine tough. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see `GET` requests that fail with a 404? Check your `basePath` setting in your karma config file.